# Erro com uso da função removeChild do JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou usando o javascript para fazer com que um label e um input do tipo text apareçam após a seleção de um dos radioButtons do meu código, que no caso são dois, e caso um seja selecionado, o outro desaparece automaticamente.

O código está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema é que aparece um erro no console do navegador que está me dando um toc, e se ele está aparecendo é porque isso poderá gerar um problema no futuro...

Erro: **index.html:44 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at HTMLInputElement.cpf_option.onclick**

Código fonte:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="DivPrincipal">
        <label>CPF</label>
        <input type="radio" name="cpf_cnpj_options" value="CPF" id="cpf_options">
        <label>CNPJ</label>
        <input type="radio" name="cpf_cnpj_options" value="CNPJ" id="cnpj_options">       
    </div>


    <script>       
        var radionButtons = document.getElementsByName("cpf_cnpj_options")
        var cpf_option = document.querySelector("#cpf_options");
        var cnpj_option = document.querySelector("#cnpj_options");

        var label_cpf = document.createElement("label");
        label_cpf.innerHTML = "CPF";
        var input_cpf = document.createElement("input");
        var attrPlaceHolderCpf = document.createAttribute("placeholder");
        attrPlaceHolderCpf.value = "CPF";
        input_cpf.setAttributeNode(attrPlaceHolderCpf);

        var label_cnpj = document.createElement("label");
        label_cnpj.innerHTML = "CNPJ";
        var input_cnpj = document.createElement("input");
        var attrPleaceHolder = document.createAttribute("placeholder");
        attrPleaceHolder.value = "CNPJ";
        input_cnpj.setAttributeNode(attrPleaceHolder);

        cpf_option.onclick = function () {
            for (let index = 0; index < radionButtons.length; index++) {
                if (radionButtons[index] ==  cpf_option) {
                    document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").appendChild(label_cpf)
                    document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").appendChild(input_cpf)
                }           
            }            
            document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(label_cnpj)
            document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(input_cnpj)              
        }

        cnpj_option.onclick = function () {
            for (let index = 0; index < radionButtons.length; index++) {
                if (radionButtons[index] == cnpj_option) {
                    document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").appendChild(label_cnpj)
                    document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").appendChild(input_cnpj)
                }                
            }            
            document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(label_cpf)
            document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(input_cpf)                
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está ocorrendo que na hora de usar o `removeChild`, o elemento criado ainda não é filho da `div#DivPrincipal`, ou seja, ele apenas foi criado, mas ainda não colocado na div.

Por exemplo, ao clicar a primeira vez no radio CNPJ, o label e o input referente ao CPF foram criados, mas não existem na div, e vice-versa.

O que deve ser feito é verificar se os elementos existem na div antes de tentar removê-los. Você pode apenas verificar se o label existe, usando `.closest()`, em duas partes do código:

Aqui, referente ao CNPJ:

```
if(label_cnpj.closest("#DivPrincipal")){        
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(label_cnpj)
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(input_cnpj)              
}
```

E aqui, referente ao CPF:

```
if(label_cpf.closest("#DivPrincipal")){
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(label_cpf)
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(input_cpf)                
}
```

### Compatibilidade IE11

Como o métoto `.closest()` não possui suporte no IE11, você pode usar `.querySelectorAll()` com `.length` (ou então usar [este polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)). Isso irá contar quantos elementos do seletor existe na div, e se houver pelo menos 1, irá entrar no `if`:

No CNPJ:

```
if(document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").querySelectorAll("input[placeholder='CNPJ']").length){
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(label_cnpj)
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(input_cnpj)              
}
```

No CPF:

```
if(document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").querySelectorAll("input[placeholder='CPF']").length){
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(label_cpf)
   document.getElementById("DivPrincipal").removeChild(input_cpf)                
}
```

Lembrando que no seletor `"input[placeholder='CPF']"` deve ser exatamente o mesmo `placeholder` do respectivo campo.

### Sugestão

Você ainda pode reduzir e melhorar a leitura cacheando a `document.getElementById("DivPrincipal")` em uma variável:

```
var divprincipal = document.getElementById("DivPrincipal");
```

Com isso você não precisa repetir `document.getElementById("DivPrincipal")` várias vezes.

Exemplo:

```js
var radionButtons = document.getElementsByName("cpf_cnpj_options")
var cpf_option = document.querySelector("#cpf_options");
var cnpj_option = document.querySelector("#cnpj_options");

var label_cpf = document.createElement("label");
label_cpf.innerHTML = "CPF";
var input_cpf = document.createElement("input");
var attrPlaceHolderCpf = document.createAttribute("placeholder");
attrPlaceHolderCpf.value = "CPF";
input_cpf.setAttributeNode(attrPlaceHolderCpf);

var label_cnpj = document.createElement("label");
label_cnpj.innerHTML = "CNPJ";
var input_cnpj = document.createElement("input");
var attrPleaceHolder = document.createAttribute("placeholder");
attrPleaceHolder.value = "CNPJ";
input_cnpj.setAttributeNode(attrPleaceHolder);


var divprincipal = document.getElementById("DivPrincipal");
cpf_option.onclick = function () {
   for (let index = 0; index < radionButtons.length; index++) {
       if (radionButtons[index] ==  cpf_option) {
           divprincipal.appendChild(label_cpf)
           divprincipal.appendChild(input_cpf)
       }           
   }    
   if(divprincipal.querySelectorAll("input[placeholder='CNPJ']").length){
      divprincipal.removeChild(label_cnpj)
      divprincipal.removeChild(input_cnpj)              
   }
}

cnpj_option.onclick = function () {
   for (let index = 0; index < radionButtons.length; index++) {
       if (radionButtons[index] == cnpj_option) {
           divprincipal.appendChild(label_cnpj)
           divprincipal.appendChild(input_cnpj)
       }                
   }
   if(divprincipal.querySelectorAll("input[placeholder='CPF']").length){
      divprincipal.removeChild(label_cpf)
      divprincipal.removeChild(input_cpf)                
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="DivPrincipal">
  <label>CPF</label>
  <input type="radio" name="cpf_cnpj_options" value="CPF" id="cpf_options">
  <label>CNPJ</label>
  <input type="radio" name="cpf_cnpj_options" value="CNPJ" id="cnpj_options">       
</div>
```

### Usando try...catch

Outra forma é ignorando o erro com [try..catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). O bloco `try{}` irá tentar executar o código, e caso haja erro, nenhum aviso de erro será exibido. O bloco `catch(e){}` retorna o erro no argumento `e`, mas você só vai usar o bloco `catch` caso queira tratar o erro, que parece não ser o caso. Ficaria assim:

No CNPJ:

```
try{
   divprincipal.removeChild(label_cnpj)
   divprincipal.removeChild(input_cnpj)              
}catch(e){}
```

No CPF:

```
try{
   divprincipal.removeChild(label_cpf)
   divprincipal.removeChild(input_cpf)                
}catch(e){}
```

Comment: Eu não estava conseguindo pegar o elemento divPrincipal, mas agora deu certo.
E a propósito, sua resposta foi muito completa, me ajudou a entender mais sobre o funcionamento do JS em relação ao HTML.